# Feathersui AS3 unshift new items if they don't exist in_arry

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a feathersui list component and I was wondering if there is a way to unshift a new item to the beginning of the list IF it doesn't current exist in the list. What I would like to do is something like the below (most is already done except the 'if it doesn't exist part):

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++)
{
    if(resultsArray[i].notification_id DOES NOT EXIST IN itemListArray)
    {
    this.itemListArray.unshift({notificationID: resultsArray[i].notification_id,
        notificationText: resultsArray[i].message,
        notificationType: resultsArray[i].notification_type,
        notificationDest: resultsArray[i].destination,
        notificationDestID: resultsArray[i].destination_id,
        dateAdded: resultsArray[i].date_added});
    }
}
```

I know PHP has `in_array` so hoping someone knows an AS3 equivalent.

Thanks

Comment: is the if condition should be resultsArray[i].notification_id DOES NOT EXIST IN itemListArray?

Answer (score 0):

Define a dictionary before the loop to get all the notificationID which itemListArray contains.

Array has a indexOf function, you can search item by that function. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf()

In your case, the array isn't directly contains the notification_id, so it won't work

```
var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

for each (var obj:Object in itemListArray) {
     dict[obj.notification_id] = true;
}

for(var i:int = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++)
{
     if(!dict[resultsArray[i].notification_id])
     {
          dict[resultsArray[i].notification_id] = true;

          this.itemListArray.unshift({notificationID: resultsArray[i].notification_id}, notificationText: resultsArray[i].message,
                                      notificationType: resultsArray[i].notification_type,
                                      notificationDest: resultsArray[i].destination,
                                      notificationDestID: resultsArray[i].destination_id,
                                      dateAdded: resultsArray[i].date_added}););
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at indexOf -> [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29)
it will return the position of the item, if it doesnt exist it will return -1

```
if(itemListArray.indexOf(resultsArray[i].notification_id) == -1){
    // item i doesnt exist
}
```